# Why the output of printf("%d" +1) is d but printf("%%%d"+1) is %d?

Tags: c

Why is that the output of

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
printf("%d"+1);
}
```

is **d** but the output of

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
 printf("%%%d"+1);
}
```

is **%d** and not **%%d** ??

Comment: In a printf format string, the format specifier `%%` means to print `%` . If you used `puts` isntead you would see `%%d`.

Answer (score 2):

`"%d"+1` by pointer arithmetic takes you to the second char in the char array which is `d`.

In the string literal `"%%%d"+1` leaves you with `"%%d"` which is interpreted as `%d` by `printf`. Since `%%` is escaped to `%`.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing pointer arithmetic. `"%d"+1` is `"d"` and `"%%%d"+1` is `"%%d"` (it's like you are skipping the first character of the string).

But, as the [documentation of printf()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) explains, the percent sign (`%`) is a special character in the string format argument of `printf()`. It introduces a "conversion specifications".

Because it is a special character it needs a special sequence (a conversion specification, in fact) in order to be able to print a literal `%`. And the conversion specification designated to print a literal `%` is exactly `%%`, as you can see from the first row of the conversion specifications table in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `+1` in `printf` which will in turn skip the one character i.e. `%` in your case. after skipping `%`character you will be left with `%%d`, since `%%` is used to print `%` character. Output will be `%d`.