# `% a` in string reads as a point in memory

Tags: c, printf, c-strings, modulo

I am using the following code in a small program demonstrating expression behavior:

```
c = a % b;
d = b % a;
printf("\nc = a % b\n"
       "d = b % a\n"
       "  a = %d\n"
       "  b = %d\n"
       "  c = %d\n"
       "  d = %d\n\n",
       a, b, c, d);
```

This is outputting as follows:

```
c = a % b
d = b  0x0.0000000000008p-1022
  a = 5
  b = 7
  c = 5
  d = 2
```

I have tried escaping the modulo operators in the string with no change in the output:

```
c = a % b;
d = b % a;
printf("\nc = a \% b\n"
       "d = b \% a\n"
       "  a = %d\n"
       "  b = %d\n"
       "  c = %d\n"
       "  d = %d\n\n",
       a, b, c, d);
```

What I'm wondering is: why would `% a` seem to point to a place in memory when `% b` outputs as expected as a string?  Additionally, why would escaping the modulo symbol not resolve the issue?

Edit (resolved):

Thanks everyone for the comments and answers; I was able to find the full details from your resonses.

This question is a duplicate of the following which can be referenced for more information:

- [Why is percentage character not escaped with backslash in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17811531/why-is-percentage-character-not-escaped-with-backslash-in-c)
- [How to escape the % (percent) sign in C's printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860159/how-to-escape-the-percent-sign-in-cs-printf)

White space is ignored following `%` and printf will use the next non-white space character to identify a conversion specifier.  The reason this did not effect `"c = a % b"` is because `%b` is not a valid conversion specifier.

The reason `%%` must be used to escape the `%` symbol is because `%`'s usage here is specific to printf and must follow the escape rules of printf, which differ from the escape rules of `\` inherited from C.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32095786/10871073 TL;DR: To print a `%` character with `printf` you need to specify `%%`.

Comment: Reading the [printf manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) will tell you that `%a` is a conversion specifier whereas `%b` is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To escape the symbol '%' in the format string you need to double it like

```
printf("\nc = a %% b\n"
```